# String pattern replace using sed in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I would like to remove the "AS" part in the below string,

```
CONV.BUY AS BUY, CONV.CUSTOM1 AS CUSTOM1 , TP.BUY AS BUY, TP.CUSTOM1 AS CUSTOM1
```

should be changed to

```
CONV.BUY, CONV.CUSTOM1, TP.BUY, TP.CUSTOM1
```

What i did is

```
echo $string |  sed -e 's/ AS.*\,/\,/g'
```

which gives

```
CONV.BUY, TP.CUSTOM1 AS CUSTOM1
```

Two fields are filtered off in that sed. Is there any better solution to achieve my objective without using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]AS[^,]*//g'
```

- `[[:blank:]]AS` matches `AS` preceded by a whitespace, then `[^,]*` matches upto the next `,`. All such matched portions are removed by replacing with null.

**Example:**

```
% sed 's/[[:blank:]]AS[^,]*//g' <<<'CONV.BUY AS BUY, CONV.CUSTOM1 AS CUSTOM1 , TP.BUY AS BUY, TP.CUSTOM1 AS CUSTOM1'
CONV.BUY, CONV.CUSTOM1, TP.BUY, TP.CUSTOM1
```

Comment: Perfect.. if you dont mind, can you please explain `AS[^,]+` part in sed? and how it replaces even instances without a comma

Comment: @OptimusPrime Sure. Note that here `AS[^,]*` would do, no need for `+` (which is a Exteneded regex pattern, matches one or more of the preceding token). So in `AS[^,]*`, `AS` matches `AS` literally, `[^,]` matches any character except `,`, the following `*` matches zero or more of such characters, so it eventually matches everything till next `,`.

Comment: Makes Sense!!! One more question, can we do adjustments within that sed to make `AS` case insensitive? i.e. match if it is `AS` or `as`?

Comment: @OptimusPrime Do `sed 's/[[:blank:]][AaSs][^,]*//g'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negated character class as

```
sed 's/AS[^,]*//g'
```

- `[^,]*` Matches zero or more non `,` characters. Which means that it matches till the immediate `,` and replace it with null

**Example**

```
>>> echo "EONV.BUY AS BUY, CONV.CUSTOM1 AS CUSTOM1 , TP.BUY AS BUY, TP.CUSTOM1 AS CUSTOM1" | gsed 's/AS[^,]*//g'
EONV.BUY , CONV.CUSTOM1 , TP.BUY , TP.CUSTOM1
```